# Has anyone used April Tags with ROS?

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My adviser had pointed me in the direction of [these](http://april.eecs.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/AprilTags) but it looks like they require their own OS/program.  Has anyone used these in conjunction with ROS and could speak to their performance or ease of use?

ROSHydro with 12.04, three Kinects I'm trying to combine into one universal frame and image.

Edit: http://wiki.ros.org/april_tk http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/april_tags_node.html looks like some tools have been developed.  Has anyone used these as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105881/has-anyone-used-april-tags-with-ros?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about "AprilTags", but they look pretty much the same as AR tags. Check out this package by Scott Niekum -- http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar, it's a ROS wrapper for the Alvar AR tag library. It works really well and seems quite robust.

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-12-03**:
I've used both april tags and AR tags. As of this summer, the ar_track_alvar package was easier to get up and running, but I haven't tried it in Hydro.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-03**:
But which is better (apriltags_ros vs ar-track-alvar) in terms of localisation accuracy ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've put together a package to use AprilTags sometime ago based of a C++ library I found [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kaess/apriltags/). I've been meaning to polish it up for a while but haven't found time to do it. Your welcome to use what I have as a starting place.

https://derekjchow@bitbucket.org/derekjchow/april_tags

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2